# I created two instances for a "singleTask" Activity. Is it a BUG for android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I created an android issue: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42603)

I know you may not believe but it's true. The key point is that -FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK will create multiple tasks with the same taskAffinity.

As said in the google doc, MULTIPLE_TASK should only be used as a Launcher.

Here is how I create this bug:
1.Prepare 3 activities, A1, A2, L. L - Launcher(maybe singleInstance), A2 - singleTask, A1 A2 have the same taskAffinity

2.L starts A1 with MULTIPLE_TASK. mHistory = L->[task1: A1(top)]

3.A1 starts A2. mHistory = L->[task1: A1->A2(top)]

4.press HOME, starts L.  mHistory = [task1: A1->A2]->HOME->L(top)

5.L starts A1 with MULTIPLE_TASK.  mHistory = [task1: A1->A2]->HOME->L->[task2: A1(top)]

6.A1 starts A2. mHistory = [task1: A1->A2]->HOME->L->[task2: A1->A2(top)]

7.Now we get two instances of A2 - which is the singleTask Activity

The BUG is because of this flag - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`. It allows to create multiple tasks with the same taskAffinity. When we are trying to find an exsiting task for singleTask A2, it first compares the taskAffinity, not `Activity.componentName()`.

The bug code is in `com/android/server/am/ActivityStack.java`

```
line 2742 - `startActivityUncheckedLocked()`

line 520 which is in `findTaskLocked()` - first compare the taskAffinity
```